# What is the domain of ZFC as a first-order theory?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory

When formalizing a first-order theory in ZFC, we say the domain (of variables) of the theory $D$ is a set. As ZFC is a first-order theory, its domain should also be a set, but the set of all sets doesn't exist.

To me, there seem to be two possible fixes.

One is to formalize ZFC within a stronger theory, so a first-order language is then rewritten to possibly have as a domain something other than a set. This seems problematic, as it might disrupt some properties of first-order logic. Specifically, I'm unsure of whether we could get something like Zorn's lemma to hold and so it doesn't seem obvious that compactness holds.

The other is that we keep the domain a metatheoretical set (of the metatheory ZFC), but this is obviously then different from the concept of a set in the theory ZFC. I'm unsure if this places some extra restrictions on what we can do within the theory ZFC.

Is either of these approaches correct, or close to correct? And how do we resolve these issues that I mention?

Comment: There is no such thing as the domain of a theory. Domains belong to interpretations, not to theories.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I meant the variables of a language. A language has a set of free/bound variables it pulls from — every set would have to be included in this set. Also, sure, how do we deal with models having a set as a domain, too?

Comment: There is no such thing as the domain (of variables) of a theory. Domains belong to interpretations, not to theories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When formalizing a first-order theory in ZFC, we say the domain of the theory $D$ is a set.

No, the domain does not belong to a theory but rather to an *interpretation* of the language that the theory is written in. There are many different interpretations one could give a language and (except in the case where there are interpretations with finite domains) many essentially different interpretations that satisfy a given theory.

> As ZFC is a first-order theory, its domain should also be a set, but the set of all sets doesn't exist.

With the above correction in mind, what's actually the case is that the domain of any interpretation of the language of set theory is a set. Such interpretations that also satisfy the ZFC axioms are called models of ZFC. As mentioned above, these are far from unique… in fact, if any models exist at all, there are models with domains of every infinite cardinality. And yeah, the domains are sets, so they don't contain every set. There's no problem with that, why should they? (The membership relation for a model also need not have anything to do with the real membership relation, though we are often interested in models where they coincide.)

> To me, there seem to be two possible fixes.

There is nothing to fix. The purpose of models of ZFC is not to contain all of the sets of the "real world", but rather to be a structure that obeys all the ZFC axioms. The collection of all "real-world" sets is (should we choose to conceive of it this way) a proper class satisfying the ZFC axioms, but that's not really relevant.